# Como registrar falta em sistema de ponto eletrônico?

Tags: php

estou com uma dúvida que é voltada pra lógica de programação.
Criei um sistema de ponto que armazena a hora que o usuário bate o ponto.

Agora preciso também armazenar o motivo das faltas: Feriado, Folta, Atestado. Porém, eu não sei qual seria o gatilho (evento) que deveria registrar faltas...

Eu não tenho um computador que fiquei ligado no sistema o tempo todo pra usar um gatilho de hora, sem contar que seria necessário um long-polling pra fazer a verificação de hora com php.

Gostaria de saber se há uma forma simples de registrar no banco de dados quando um funcionário não marcou ponto.

Answer (score 2):

Hoje em dia existe normas específicas para desenvolvimento de ponto eletrônico.

> 1. Desde 25/08/2009 todas as empresas que adotam o registro eletrônico de ponto devem utilizar o Programa de Tratamento de Registro de Ponto
>      (PTRP), bem como realizar o cadastro (CAREP), previstos na Portaria nº
>      1.510/2009. Embora a utilização do Registrador Eletrônico de Ponto (REP) só seja obrigatória a partir de 01/09/2011, as empresas que já o
>      utilizam devem cadastrá-lo imediatamente no CAREP (Perguntas e
>      Respostas nº 3, 52, 114 e 118).
> 2. Qualquer sistema de controle de ponto que utilize meios eletrônicos para identificar o empregado, tratar, armazenar ou enviar qualquer
>      tipo de informação de marcação de ponto deverá atender aos requisitos
>      da Portaria nº 1.510/2009 (Perguntas e Respostas nº 58).

Fonte [Ministério do Trabalho: Sistema de Registro Eletrônico de Ponto - SREP](http://portal.mte.gov.br/pontoeletronico/)

Quais são os principais pontos da Portaria MTE 1.510/2009?

- Proíbe todo tipo de restrição à marcação de ponto, marcações automáticas e alteração dos dados registrados;
- Estabelece requisitos para o equipamento de registro de ponto, identificado pela sigla REP (Registrador Eletrônico dePonto);
- Obriga a emissão de comprovante da marcação a cada registro efetuado no REP
- Estabelece os requisitos para os programas que farão o tratamento dos dados oriundos do REP;
- Estabelece os formatos de relatórios e arquivos digitais de registros de ponto que o empregador deverá manter e apresentar à fiscalização do trabalho

Quais os principais requisitos do REP?

- Ter como finalidade exclusiva a marcação de ponto;
- Possuir memória das marcações de ponto que não possa ser alterada ou apagada;
- Emitir comprovante a cada marcação efetuada pelo trabalhador;
- Não possuir mecanismo que permita marcações automáticas ou restrições às marcações

**Cuidado, caso haja alguma fiscalização na empresa que utiliza seu software e o mesmo não estiver dentro das normas, é problema na certa (MULTA).**

Se depois de ler toda a norma para software de ponto eletrônico e mesmo assim ainda quiser desenvolver esta solução, é importante entender a [CLT-Consolidação das Leis do Trabalho](http://Consolida%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20das%20Leis%20do%20Trabalho) e consultar um bom profissional de recursos humanos.

Desenvolver um software de registro de ponto está complicado, antigamente para você ter uma ideia com relação a sua dúvida, bastaria você definir um tempo limite de atraso, por exemplo, `atrasou de 5min a 10min perde 1 hora`, além disso perde `meio expediente`.

Comment: Agradeço as informações...mas e quanto a minha dúvida?

Comment: Leia último parágrafo, era assim que eu definia falta em um programa antigo de ponto que eu desenvolvi. Os limites sempre eram definidos com o responsável pelo setor pessoal.

Comment: Mas a questão é: o sistema que você desenvolveu tinha o recurso de disparar um evento  automático de acordo com a hora que o tal responsável passou pra você, certo? Eu não acho possível disparar um evento automático em um sistema web (que é o meu caso), e é ai que se encontra meu problema, eu não sei como disparar o evento que registra falta, espero que tenha conseguido me explicar agora rs

Answer (score 1):

Se não houve registro de ponto no dia E não teve registro de qualquer outra coisa que abone a sua falta (férias, feriado, final de semana, folga, período futuro, etc.), considere via aplicação que é uma falta.

A lógica seria registrar o que possa abonar a falta daquele funcionário naquele dia. E se não tiver horários de entrada/saída ou o abonador não pode ser outra coisa senão uma falta.

Comment: acho que não consegui me explicar...rs
Gostaria de saber em qual momento fazer essa verificação, entende?
O correto seria no fim do dia, porém me toquei que há dias que ninguém vai acessar o sistema ex: domingos, feriados, etc entao não sei quando fazer a verificação se houve registro...

Sendo bem especifico, onde eu coloco o "gatilho" que fará a verificaçao?